# cakephp hasAndBelongsToMany

Tags: cakephp, associations

My 'Reservation' model and 'Profile' model have hasAndBelongsToMany association.

Here is my Reservation Model.

```
 class Reservation extends AppModel {
   .
   .
   var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Profile' => array(
        'className' => 'Profile',
        'joinTable' => 'profiles_reservations',
        'foreignKey' => 'reservation_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'profile_id',
        'unique' => true,
    )
);
```

And Here is my Profile Model.

```
class Profile extends AppModel  {
     var $name = 'Profile';
}
```

And here is my controller .

```
 function prac3($lname, $fname) {
    $profiles = $this->Profile->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                    'Profile.lname LIKE' => $lname.'%',
                    'Profile.fname LIKE' => '%'.$fname.'%'
            ),
            'order'=>array( 'Profile.created DESC' ),
    ));
    $this->set('profiles', $profiles);
 }
```

And here is my view.

```
 <?php
if($profiles) {
    foreach($profiles as $key => $profile): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $profile['Profile']['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $profile['Profile']['lname'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $profile['Profile']['fname'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $profile['Profile']['home_phone'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    endforeach;
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

I wanna get ['Reservation']['name'] in the view using Profile model. How can I do this?

Comment: add to Profile model HABTM realtionships

Comment: I did that before but that made problem. When I add new reservation and profile, the rows that has the profile id were disappeared in the profiles_reservations Table.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Profile class

```
    class Profile extends AppModel  {
         var $name = 'Profile';

         var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
             'Reservation' => array(
                 'className' => 'Reservation',
                 'joinTable' => 'profiles_reservations',
                 'foreignKey' => 'profile_id',
                 'associationForeignKey' => 'reservation_id',
                 'unique' => true, // More about update below
         )
    }
```

In Your `find()` method shoud use recursive:

```
$profiles = $this->Profile->find('all', array(
        //...
        'recursive' => 2,
));
```

or Containable behavior:

```
$this->Profile->Behaviors->load('Containable');  

$profiles = $this->Profile->find('all', array(
        //...
        'contain' => array(
                'Reservation',
        ),
        'recursive' => -1,
));
```

and Your reservetion will be in array like `$profiles['Reservation'][n]['name']`.

Additional, in Your comment You wrote "*When I add new reservation and profile, the rows that has the profile id were disappeared in the profiles_reservations Table.*"
Because You are using `'unique' => true` in `$hasAndBelongsToMany` property. The cookbook says:

> If true (default value) CakePHP will first delete existing relationship records in the foreign keys table before inserting new ones. Existing associations need to be passed again when updating.

See: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

Comment: Then do I need to use 'unique' => 'keepExisting' if I want to save all the records?

Comment: Read documentation. I don't know what is Your idea:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class ReservationsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Profiles', [
            'joinTable' => 'reservation_profiles',
        ]);
    }
}
class ProfilesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Reservations', [
            'joinTable' => 'reservation_profiles',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then as you can see ReservationsTable is the model that relate Reservation to Profiles using reservation_profiles table to do that Profiles does the same. You don't need to have a model for reservation_profiles, but you must have this table on your databse, I sugest you to use migration to create them. Finally in your controller, this could be in your ReservationController you call

```
$this->Reservation->Profiles->find()->where(['condition'=> 'param']);
```

This may solve your problem, explainning ($this) refer to the Controller class, ->REservation refer to the model Reservation -> Profiles refer to related model to the class Reservation model, ->find()... refer to the query executed. If you need more https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations